# Incorrect input warning comes more than once

Tags: c, input, eof

I have a problem with incorrect input in my program. It reads coordinate and calculate max length from coordinates which are in array. It should reads until EOF. Correct format of coordinates is e.g. [5,10]. Problem is, when I write e.g. "asdf" . Then I get 4x Incorrect input and I want it only once. Could someone help me? Thank you in advance.

```
 while ((c1=(scanf(" %c %lf %c %lf %c", &f, &cx, &g, &cy, &h))) != EOF){
 if (c1 != 5 || h != ']' || g != ',' || f != '['){
        printf("Incorrect input. \n");
        continue;
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < pocet; i++) {
        u = polex[i] - cx;
        v = poley[i] - cy;

        result = sqrt((u*u) + (v*v));
        if (result>max){
            max = result;
        }

    }
    printf("Max: %g\n", max);
    max = 0;
}
```

Comment: Clear the `stdin` on invalid input by using `int c; while((c = getchar()) != '\n');`

Comment: Thanks, it works, but then EOF (CTRL+D) will not end the program.

Answer (score 5):

If `scanf` doesn't read all the formats (i.e. it returns less than `5` in your case) then you will be out of sync as the next call to `scanf` will try to read from where the last one left off.

I suggest you use [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) first to read the whole line, and then use `sscanf` to parse the input. I.e. something like

```
while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != NULL)
{
    c1 = sscanf(buffer, ...);
    ...
}
```